Python black formatting only one file in project
I've installed black formatting in the venv directory of my project. In my project, I have, among other files:
.vscode/settings.json
and
djblogger/djblogger/settings/base.py
in the settings.json is the following:
"editor.formatOnSave": false, // enable per language
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
// Workspace Settings
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/Users/Owner/Documents/GitHub/django-project-djblogger/venv/Scripts",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "-l 120"
],

When I add extra blank lines in settings.json, then save, the blank lines are removed.
When I add extra blank lines in base.py, then save, the blank lines are not removed.
How do I get black formatting to work for all files, not just settings.json?

According to documentation You can use
black {source_file_or_directory}

So try to point path to Your main project folder
